# Embedded Assets in Actionscript are Flipped when Displayed!

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, red5

Writing a small application in order to demonstrate certain functionality. I have an embedded asset being added to the stage which then has some listeners added to it so it can be dragged around. This data is stored in a remote shared object so that other clients can drag the object around as well.

The problem is my object is flipped horizontally when loaded... and ideas why this is happening?

Code here: http://pastebin.com/TjegG71W

Comment: That's strange. Don't see anything likely in your code.. can you try some sanity checks, like replacing the png with a jpeg, or a different component (like a Label or whatever)? My blind guess is something about the png or the png decoder making Flash simply read it in backwards.

Comment: Try cleaning your project and rebuilding it.

Comment: A label is displayed fine.. cleaned and rebuilt the project and tried a jpeg. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were some bugs in Flex 4.1 around a new feature that was introduced called [Layout Mirroring](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Layout+Mirroring).  Upgrading to Flex 4.5 should fix these of them and if you can't upgrade yet you can try setting the layoutDirection style to "ltr" on your Application.

Comment: Actually had to set it to "rtl" but that explains it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said this is just a demo or proof of concept, you can fix this for display until we get to the bottom of it.  Add this into line 45ish where you're creating the component:

```
 bannerui = new UIComponent();
 bannerui.scaleX = -1;
```

For debugging what is going on - I have a hunch that the scaleX property is getting jacked around with at some point and getting set to -1 on one of the components.  Lets try adding a listener for it and seeing what get traced to the console (add to any other parent components of the flipped image well):

line 45ish:

```
 bannerui = new UIComponent();
 bannerui.addEventListener( 'scaleXChanged' , onScaleXChanged );
```

add this method:

```
    private function onScaleXChanged( e :Event){
        trace( bannerui.scaleX );
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a shot tomorrow. I have a scaleX = -1 on it for the time being. Will report back.

Comment: Plus, you get to use an undocumented event (scaleXChanged)  :D

Comment: Nothing happening there, checked the uicomponent and the bitmap object.

Comment: Image instead of Bitmap?  Also try adding it into the rawChildren display list, just for kicks..

Answer (score 0):

I was building for 4.1.0... built for 4.5.1 and it works..

fix: upgrade Flex SDK :P